# ld-uClibc.so.0: No Such file or directory when running qemu-mipsel-static

Tags: qemu

BLUF: When executing `sudo chroot . ./qemu-mipsel-static ./bin/busybox` from the squashfs-root folder the error `/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0: No such file or directory` is returned. Failing to figure out how to fix the error.

I am in the early stages of analyzing a firmware update for a consumer router. Busybox is included with the firmware and I am trying to see what I can run with it in an emulated environment.

I see that a version of the uClibc library is included with the firmware: `/lib/ld-uClibc-0.9.29.so`

I tried symlinking ld-uClibc-0.9.29.so to ld-uClibc.so.0 but I receive `ln: failed to create symbolic link 'ld-uClibc.so.0': Operation not permitted` so my understanding of the symbolic linking process in this context is certainly coming up short.

How can I get qemu-mipsel-static to recognize the library? Do I need to install a different library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out that the directories I was working in were mounted as a share in a VirtualBox guest. By default symbolic linking is not enabled on a shared folder as the host OS might not be able to understand a symbolic link. More information can be found here in the second comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18572?cversion=0&cnum_hist=2

My problem was solved once enabling symbolic linking for my shared drive and then creating a symbolic link from squashfs-root/lib/ld-uClibc-0.9.29.so to squashfs-root/lib/ld-uClic.so.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the path to the device files directory using the `-L` switch